# VB.Net Filter Array Equivalent From VB6

Tags: vb.net, arrays, vb6, filter, arraylist

Been googling for an hour and can't seem to find the answer. The following will remove "stupid" and prints out "hello world"

```
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("hello", "stupid", "world")
Dim newArr As Variant: newArr = Filter(arr, "stupid", False)
Debug.Print Join(newArr, " ")
```

What is the VB.Net equivalent for Filter? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Edit: (I'm looking for a 2.0 NET Framework solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .NET 2.0 you can use the [Array.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
Dim arr As String() = New String() {"hello", "stupid", "world"}  
Dim newArr As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, AddressOf RemoveElements)
```

Using this predicate:

```
Private Shared Function RemoveElements(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Return Not s.Equals("stupid")
End Function
```

Comment: Can you use lambda functions from VB.Net in .Net 2?

Comment: @MarkJ Thanks again Mark!  At least one of us is paying attention to what I'm doing.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Seems odd to me this is easier to do in VBA or VB6 than in .NET :/.  I miss the filter function

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps (Assumes VB 10):

```
Dim arr As String() = {"hello", "stupid", "world"}

Dim filteredArray = (from s in arr
                     Where s <> "stupid"
                     Select s).ToArray()
```

An alternative is to use Except (which is available in .Net 3.5):

```
Dim words As String() = {"hello", "stupid", "world"}
Dim excludedWords As String()  = {"stupid"}

Dim filteredArray = words.Except(excludedWords).ToArray()
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks. Your words.Except solution works for framework 3.5. Anybody know how to do it in 2.0?